# App not waiting for method to finish executing

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a method `getnamefornumbers` which call a soap based web service(sudzc generated), which return a some data which i store in array to use.
But problem is that when i call the method it takes its time to execute and code after this method also executing, this result in null array.

what can i do so when this method completes its work then rest of the code executes.

Comment: In Objective-C, I recommend camel notation (getNameForNumbers), otherwiseitisalsmostimpossibletoreadyourmethodnamesjustsayin'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `NSURLConnection` delegation methods. In an async environment that's the normal behavior:

1. You make a call (in an async way)
2. The application keeps running (after you make the 1. call the program continues with the rest of the instructions)

So you have to two solutions, make it sync, so you will only continue after an answer comes (in your case the array is filled), which I would probably disencourage. Or, you make it async, and use the array when you actually have it.

As for specifics in how to implement this, more details must be provided, in order for me to advise you.

---

**Update 1.0**

```
-(void)requestConnectionToServer{

   NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:@"myWebServiceURL"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.reference=aReference;

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:20.0];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDelegate Implementation

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Response:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction %@",error);
}
```

---

**Update 2.0**

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        myArray = [MyWebServiceAccess getnamefornumbers];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [myArray makeSomething];
        });
        });
```

Comment: i tried @syncronuis(self) {//calling my method but same problem}, can u write a small code so it will be better to understand.

Comment: web service is generated through sudz online generator so i don't want to make changes in that it will take too much time.. can u tell me how to make rest of the app wait until this method completes its execution ..

Comment: Don't mistake webservice, with the actual class that access it. When you say "web service is generated through sudz online generator" I am guessing you are saying that you already have the code to access the webservice. Check my new update.

Comment: nope not working still getting the null array and getting actual values after fee seconds

Comment: Would have to see it for myself to know what's going on.

Comment: [classobj getNamesForNumbers] i want the app to wait until this method completes its execution... @syncronised, wait, nscondition, nslock ... any thing that can help ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13298/discussion-between-jacky-boy-and-sweet-jenny)

Comment: Well, you just don't pick something from your hat and see if it works... You have 4 alternatives: 1) Talk to me in the chat to see if this works, 2) send me an email so I can see what's going with your project 3) Wait for someone else to help you 4) Figure it out yourself.

Comment: you know boss is like a dipper always on your a** and full of sh*t :) ... thats why didn't reply, a temporary fix is working now but i have to do in a standard way, then we will get back on this ... thanks a lot for replies and help ... muaah :)

Comment: As a guy I used to know told me once: `Do it right the first time, or it will be back to bite in your ass.` Guess what, he was right...

Comment: Well, buy some ointment for later then. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom delegates.You should define the protocol and delegate the current class to responsible for the class which performs getnamefornumbers. Once the operation done , you should return to caller class.

Here is the example of protocols http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: i am calling this in app delegate and need to populate here, root view is a uitableview i have to show data in uitableview but all the work is getting done before and web service data is receiving late ... making all the things go wrong :(